# Prove a claim on the boundary of A ($\partial A$)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, metric-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ (A is a Set), and let $x \in \partial A$ (in other words; x is a limit point)

**Note:** $\partial A$ refers to the boundary of $A$. link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)

**I want to prove the following:**

> **p is a boundary point of a set if and only if every neighborhood of p contains at least one point in the set and at least one point not in
>   the set.**

I am trying to prove this by contradiction; So I supposed:

**1)** There is a a boundary point x of the set A such that there is a neighborhood of x that contains only points from the set.

Or

**2)** There is a a boundary point x of the set A such that there is a neighborhood of x that contains only points **not** from the set.

I proved that 1 is wrong, but how could I prove that the second is wrong too?

Comment: You can express subset by $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ (in code `A\subseteq \mathbb R^n`).

Comment: What have you tried for 2)? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: The statement you want to prove (in bold) is one of the usual definition of boundary point. What is your definition of boundary? (If it doesn't differ, then there is nothing to show.)

Comment: Hi @Saad, as mentioned above I made the assumption and got stuck for hours, that's why I came to ask for some help. The only thing I found out was that x isn't in A and it's a limit point (I don't know if that is helpful)

Comment: @user251257 it is the set of points in the closure of S not belonging to the interior of S.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of curiosity, I provide here an alternative way to approach it.

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space, $E\subseteq X$ and $x\in X$. We say that $x$ is a boundary point of $E$ if it is neither an interior point nor an exterior point of $E$.

We say that $x\in\text{int}(E)$ iff there exists a positive real number $r > 0$ s.t. $B(x,r)\subseteq E$.

We say that $x\in\text{ext}(E)$ iff there exists a positive real number $R > 0$ s.t. $B(x,R)\cap E = \varnothing$.

Thus $x\in X$ is in the boundary of $E$ iff $B(x,r)\not\subseteq E$ and $B(x,r)\cap E\neq\varnothing$ for every $r > 0$.

The last statements prove what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to argue as follows: 
Let $x\in\partial A$, and consider a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N\cap A=\emptyset$.

Then $x\not\in closure(A)$: simply because $N^c$ is closed, $A\subset N^c$, and $x\not\in N^c$. A simple argument then allows you to conclude that $x\not\in\partial A$. [Hint: if $x$ is not in the closure of $A$, then it must belong to the exterior of $A$ and $\partial A = (int(A)\cup ext(A))^c$]

Comment: What is the definition of closure of a set $A$? It is the smallest **closed set** containing A. Mathematically,
$closure(A) = \cap\big\{V: A\subset V, \text{and $B$ is a closed set}\big\}$.

By the argument in my previous comment, I just showed that $A^c\backslash N$ is a closed set that contains $A$, and $x$ doesn't belong to it. Hence $x$ can't belong to the closure.

Comment: Made an error, and made notation easier. Hope this makes it clear. And $A^c$ denotes the complement of a set in my notation.

Comment: Actually it is much simpler! ∂=int(A)\ext(A) so you first line is enough

Comment: Your solution is wrong, "  is closed" you can't know for sure, you supposed there there is a neighborhood N but you know nothing about it if it's closed or not

Comment: Its not wrong. You can wlog consider an open neighborhood $N$. Why?

*Neighborhood of a point $x$ is any set $N$ such that there exists an open set $V\subseteq N$ containing $x$.*

You can just replace $N$ with $V$ in the proof, if you want.